# Aiogram не распознает PNG фото

Tags: python, aiogram

Есть следующая асинхронная функция, которая принимает фото от пользователя и сохраняет id этого фото.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако данный код работает только с Сжатым изображением в Телеграм, не сжатое изображение бот не видит, как это пофиксить? Буду очень благодарен.

Бот должен распознавать не сжатые изображения в Телеграме.

Comment: несжатое это `document`, так что лови еще и документ ну и само собой `message.document.file_id`

Comment: Заработало, благодарю